# dojo.parser.parse only working first time it's called

Tags: dojo

I have a page that when a user clicks on a link for some reporting tools, it first asks them to enter some report parameters. I get the parameters dialog as a form using AJAX, based on the id of the link. Each dialog has some dojo controls on it, so I need to parse them when the dialog appears, because it is not originally part of the page.

The first dialog when called works fine, but subsequent calls to dialogs fails to parse the dojo controls.

Example:

```
 showParametersDialog : function(doc) {
     var content = doc.firstChild.firstChild.data;
     var container = document.createElement('div');
     container.id = 'dialog';
     container.innerHTML = content;
     container.style.background = 'transparent';
     container.style.position = 'absolute';
     container.style.top = (document.body.clientHeight / 2) - 124 + "px";
     container.style.left = (document.body.clientWidth / 2) - 133 + "px";
     container.style.display = 'block';
     document.body.appendChild(container);

     // set up date fields
     var date_from = dojo.byId('date_from');
     var date_to = dojo.byId('date_to');
     try {
      date_from.value = dojo.date.locale.format(new Date(), {selector: 'date'});
      date_to.value = dojo.date.locale.format(new Date(), {selector: 'date'});
     } catch(e) {
      var now = new Date();
      date_from.value = String(now.getMonth() + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear());
      date_to.value = String(now.getMonth() + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear());
     }
     dojo.parser.parse();
    }
```

All dialogs have the common date fields.
So when I call this dialog the first time, and dojo.parser.parse() is called, it parses the controls on the dialog, but only the first time...after than, no dojo.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: Ok, I tried to use:

var list = dojo.query('[widgetId]', 'dialog');
list.forEach( 
 function(w){
  w.destroyRecursive();
});

...to destroy the widgets when the dialog is closed and I get "Object doesn't support this method" error!!! What? Of course it supports that method, it's in the docs!

I'm starting to think that using Dojo was a bad move because it is now costing me development time. I have tried the example from the website and they simply do not work. I am using 1.3.2

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of destroy recursive, you could also try using a dojo.query() call to fetch anything with a "_widgetId" in your dialog and then destroy each individually.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that with this code: dojo.query('[widgetId]', 'dialog').forEach(function(w){w.destroy();}); Every time whether I use destroy or destroyRecursive I get the same thing "Method not supported". And because the list only contained actual widgets, this make no sense. Each one should have a destroy but the system is saying no. It just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
dojo.parser.instantiate([dojo.byId("myDiv")]);
```

instead of dojo.parser.parse();
Use it on all unparsed objects.

More on this you can find here:

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/parser

Answer (score 0):

it's not that it's not parsing the second time, it's that if dojo tries to parse something more than once, it fails. You could keep track with a boolean flag whether it has been parsed already, and if not, skip the line that parses it.

```
if (!parsed)
{
    dojo.parser.parse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're missing something like `dojo.parser.parse(container)`. Otherwise, it probably tries to parse the entire document and finds *parsed* elements and stops.

(wild guess pulled from old dojo knowledge)

Comment: Here is the issue I get still: When the dialog in removed from the DOM and then re-appended after clicking the link a second time, I get "Tried to register widget with id==date_from but that id is already registered". So how do I destroy the dojo node correctly so that I can reuse it?

Thanks

Comment: There is a "destroy" function you need to call when you want to remove a widget and it's children.

Comment: None of the answers on this question are conclusive. I can witness the same behavior. Except that it is some what more random than that.